# Css is not working in compressed mode

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, css3pie

In my CSS file i use filter to show box-shadow in IE-8 . In normal mode it is working fine but for compresses version it is not working. here is my compressed css

```
.lt-ie9 .image-with-align:hover{background-color:#fff;zoom:1;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#ddddd9,direction=0,strength=1),progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#ddddd9,direction=45,strength=1),progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#ddddd9,direction=90,strength=2),progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#ddddd9,direction=135,strength=3),progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#ccccc9,direction=180,strength=10),progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#ddddd9,direction=225,strength=3),progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#ddddd9,direction=270,strength=2),progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#ddddd9,direction=315,strength=1)}
```

the reason can be because values are geeting break between the lines or there is no space between filter and progid can anybody give me any suggestion and valid reason for this .

Answer (score 1):

The comma gets ignored. You need a whitespace or a newline to paste multiple filters.

progid:xxx progid:yyy / works

progid:xxx, progid:yyy / works

progid:xxx
progid:yyy / works

progid:xxx,progid:yyy / will not work

it will be the correct one

```
.lt-ie9 .image-with-align:hover{background-color:#fff;zoom:1;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#ddddd9,direction=0,strength=1) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#ddddd9,direction=45,strength=1) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#ddddd9,direction=90,strength=2) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#ddddd9,direction=135,strength=3) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#ccccc9,direction=180,strength=10) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#ddddd9,direction=225,strength=3) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#ddddd9,direction=270,strength=2) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#ddddd9,direction=315,strength=1)}
```